# Interperting Negative Sortino Ratios

Tags: investment

I noticed when both assets sortino ratios are negative the asset with the worse return and worse downside deviation has better Sortino Ratio. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Craig Israelson made a modification to Sharpe Ratio Formula so that when excess returns are negative for both assets sharpe ratio still retains meaning. It is done by adding exponent to the denominator.  The exponent is excess return divided by absolute value of excess return. My question is can this modification also be applied to Sortino Ratio denominator?

Comment: IMO yes, you could do the exact same thing for Sortino as Craig Israelson did for Sharpe.

Comment: @nbbo2 Hmm when I apply Craig Israelson modification to Sortino Ratio when the Excess Return becomes negative the sortino ratio becomes 0.

Comment: This is the Excel formula I am using to calculate Sortino Ratio with Craig Israelson Modification "=RRI(10,C2,C122)/(SQRT(SUMSQ(CM3:CM122)/(COUNT(CM3:CM122)-1)^((RRI(10,C2,C122)-BX122)/ABS(RRI(10,C2,C122)-BX122)))*SQRT(12))"

Comment: CM3-CM122 refers to Downside Deviation. C2 refers to Portfolio Value on April 1979 and C122 refers to Portfolio Value on April 1989. BX122 refers to Risk Free Rate. SQRT (12) is done because the downside deviation is calculated from monthly returns.

Comment: @nbbo2 NVM I fixed it myself. In case person is interested "=(RRI(10,C2,C122)-BX122)/(SQRT(SUMSQ(CL3:CL122)/(COUNT(CL3:CL122)-1))*SQRT(12)^((RRI(10,C2,C122)-BX122)/ABS(RRI(10,C2,C122)-BX122)))". Now I am wondering if only one of the sharpe ratios is negative and other is positive. Is it valid to compare the two sharpe ratios? As Craig Israelsons modification creates larger negative sharpe ratios.

Comment: @nbbo2 Spoke too soon there. Same problem I am having even with Craig Israelsons modification done to Sortino Ratio denominator. The asset with the higher return and lower downside deviation has worse negative sharpe than asset with lower return and higher downside deviation.

Comment: @nbbo2 Can I just put the target return as 0% so that way I dont have to deal with the headache of trying to figure out how to get the Sortino ratio to work as expected when excess returns are negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was causing the issue here. The formula of Craig Israelson's Modification to Sharpe Ratio ie ER/(Standard Deviation^(ER/ABS(ER))requires usage of percentages and I was inputting decimal values. Consider this issue to be fixed.